Tsibble Fill Implicit Gaps
I am writing this code about Male Employment Data, and trying to apply classical decomposition, but I keep getting this:
Warning: 1 error encountered for classical_decomposition(Value, type = "additive")
[1] .data contains implicit gaps in time. You should check your data and convert implicit gaps into explicit missing values using `tsibble::fill_gaps()` if required.

The thing is that there are no gaps in my dataset.
Here is my full code:
# Read the CSV file
    employment <- read.csv("LNS12000001.csv")

# Convert DATE column to Date type
    employment$DATE <- as.Date(employment$DATE)

# Convert to tsibble
    male_employment <- as_tsibble(employment, index = DATE)

    male_employment <- male_employment |> rename(Value = LNS12000001)

    print(male_employment)

# Apply Classical Decomp

    male_employment |> model(classical_decomposition(Value, type = "additive")) |> components() |>  autoplot() + xlab("Year") + ggtitle("Classical additive decomposition of  US Male employment")


This is not reproducible. Perhaps the data are monthly or quarterly, but you are treating them as daily by using as.Date(). So only the first day of the period has data.
